# How to show ad in flurry SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ads, flurry

How to use AppCircle in flurry? I am use flurry sdk but here not find AppCircle header file.
How to who ad through flurry sdk?

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=AppCircle/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you trying to use? For the iOS SDK version 4.x or Android SDK version 3.x, you should use the docs here which support AppCircle ads as well as AppSpot: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry Sdk link With AppCircle file.firstly i am import this sdk
https://github.com/brightapps-in/Flurry-SDK-for-iPhone

Import in appdelegate:

```
#import "FlurryAPI+AppCircle.h"
```

And

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   appDelegate=(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   [FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:self];
   [FlurryAPI setAppCircleEnabled:YES];
   [FlurryAPI startSession:@"App Circle key"];
}
```

import in your class :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *banner = [FlurryAPI getHook:@"APP_MAIN_HOOK"
                                   xLoc:0
                                   yLoc:0
                                   view:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was talking to Flurry support and they said - current SDK version does not contain AppCircle. Corresponding functions will be added in later SDK versions or you can try using older SDK. I did try 2.2.5 Android SDK - it works, but AppCircle.getOffer() returns null.